# Coroutine, пропуск кадров

Tags: android, многопоточность, kotlin, coroutine

При инициализации класса идёт обновление пользователя вынесенный в корутину, при его использование получаю skipped frame, но при использование треда, такого уже нету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class UserRepo (val settings: Settings, val userServerRepo: UserServerRepo)
    {
        val userLD: MutableLiveData<User?> = MutableLiveData()

        init {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                userLD.postValue(settings.user)
                updateUserInfo()
            }

            /*
            var loadInitData = object : Thread(){
                override fun run() {
                    userLD.postValue(settings.user)
                    updateUserInfo()
                }
            }.start()*/
        }

        fun loginUser(login: String, password: String): ResultAPI<UserLogin.Result>
        {
            val result = userServerRepo.loginUser(UserLogin.Data(login, password))

            if (result.code == NetworkService.RESPONSE_OK_CODE && !result.body?.tokenType.isNullOrEmpty())
            {
                settings.tokenUser = "${result.body?.tokenType} ${result.body?.accessToken}"

                //updateUserInfo()
            }

            return result
        }

        fun updateUserInfo()
        {
            if (!settings.tokenUser.isNullOrEmpty())
            {
                userServerRepo.getUserInfo(settings.tokenUser!!).body?.let {
                    settings.user = it.user

                    userLD.postValue(it.user)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getUser(): User? {
            return userLD.value
        }
    }
```

Comment: Похоже, что до этого у вас в программе не было обращений к `Dispatchers.IO`, тут происходит инициализация `object DefaultScheduler` в котором находится `IO` диспатчер и создание самого диспатчера и из-за этого и происходит подвисание (не уверен полностью, поэтому как коммент), попробуйте просто обратиться к `Dispatchers.IO` где-нибудь заранее, где нет особой нагрузки. Но на самом деле вам тут и не нужна корутина, у вас нет `suspend` функций в ней, из-за этого она перестаёт особо и обычного потока отличаться, тут можно использовать и `Thread` или `Excecutors`.

Comment: Кстати поток в котлине можно и так запустить `Thread { /* выполняемая функция */
    }.start()` или с помощью функции `thread { /* выполняемая функция */  }`